# How to use generics as params?(Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

Code in playground is here

```
class ProductModel {
    var productID : Int = 0
    init(id:Int) {
        productID = id
    }
}


protocol GenericListProtocol {
    typealias T = ProductModel
    var list : [T] { get set }
    var filteredlist : [T] { get set }
    func setData(list : [T])
}
extension GenericListProtocol {
    func setData(list: [T]) {
        list.forEach { item in
            guard let productItem = item as? ProductModel else {
                return
            }
            print(productItem.productID)
        }
    }
}

class testProtocol {
    class func myfunc<N:GenericListProtocol>(re:N){
        var list : [ProductModel] = [ProductModel(id: 1),ProductModel(id: 2),ProductModel(id: 3),ProductModel(id: 4)]
        re.setData(list)
    }
}
```

But in the line `re.setData(list)`

get compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[ProductModel]' to expected argument
>   type '[_]'.

My Question is How to use setData method in `GenericListProtocol`?

Anyone could help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `ProductModel` type into the extension and removing the constraint from the generic protocol seems to work.

```
class ProductModel {
    var productID : Int = 0
    init(id:Int) {
        productID = id
    }
}

protocol GenericListProtocol {
    typealias T
    var list : [T] { get set }
    var filteredlist : [T] { get set }
    func setData(list : [T])
}

extension GenericListProtocol {
    func setData(list: [ProductModel]) {
        list.forEach { item in
            print(item.productID)
        }
    }
}

class testProtocol {
    class func myfunc<N:GenericListProtocol>(re:N) {
        let list : [ProductModel] = [ProductModel(id: 1),ProductModel(id: 2),ProductModel(id: 3),ProductModel(id: 4)]
        re.setData(list)
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. It was a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question interesting and thought how best we could solve it in generic way.

```
protocol Product {
    var productID : Int {get set}
}

class ProductModel: Product {
    var productID : Int = 0
    init(id:Int) {
        productID = id
    }
}

protocol GenericListProtocol {
    typealias T : Product
    var list : [T] { get set }
    var filteredlist : [T] { get set }

}

extension GenericListProtocol {
    func setData(list: [T]) {
        list.forEach { item in
            print(item.productID)
        }
    }
}

class GenericListProtocolClass : GenericListProtocol
{
    typealias T = ProductModel
    var intVal = 0

    var list =  [T]()
    var filteredlist = [T]()

}

class testProtocol {
    class func myfunc(re: GenericListProtocolClass){
        let list : [ProductModel] = [ProductModel(id: 1),ProductModel(id: 2),ProductModel(id: 3),ProductModel(id: 4)]
        re.setData(list)
    }
}


let temp = GenericListProtocolClass()
testProtocol.myfunc(temp)
```

Appreciate your thought and suggestion if it can be improved further.